# order of SIGCONT and SIGHUP sent to orphaned linux process group

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, signals

APUE says

> Since the process group is orphaned when the parentterminates, POSIX.1 requires that every process in
> the newly orphaned process group that is stopped (as our child is) be sent the hang-up signal (SIGHUP)
> followed by the continue signal (SIGCONT)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define errexit(msg) do{ perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while(0)
static void sig_hup(int signo)
{
    printf("SIGHUP received, pid = %d\n", getpid());
}
static void sig_cont(int signo)
{
    printf("SIGCONT received, pid = %d\n", getpid());
}
static void sig_ttin(int signo)
{
    printf("SIGTTIN received, pid = %d\n", getpid());
}
static void pr_ids(char *name)
{
    printf("%s: pid = %d, ppid = %d, pgrp = %d, tpgrp = %d\n",
           name, getpid(), getppid(), getpgrp(), tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO));
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c;
    pid_t pid;
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    pr_ids("parent");
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            errexit("fork error");
    } else if (pid > 0) { /* parent */
            sleep(5);
            printf("parent exit\n");
            exit(0);
    } else { /* child */
            pr_ids("child...1");
            signal(SIGCONT, sig_cont);
            signal(SIGHUP, sig_hup);
            signal(SIGTTIN, sig_ttin);
            kill(getpid(), SIGTSTP);
            //sleep(10);
            pr_ids("child...2");
            if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) != 1) {
                    printf("read error from controlling TTY, errno = %d\n", 
                                                             errno);
            }
            printf("child exit\n");
    }
    exit(0);
  }
```

program output:

> parent: pid = 2036, ppid = 1959, pgrp = 2036, tpgrp = 2036
> child...1: pid = 2037, ppid = 2036, pgrp = 2036, tpgrp = 2036
> parent exit
> xiejingfeng@xiejingfeng-desktop:/codes/apue$ SIGCONT received, pid = 2037
> SIGHUP received, pid = 2037
> child...2: pid = 2037, ppid = 1, pgrp = 2036, tpgrp = 1959
> read error from controlling TTY, errno = 5
> child exit

output is not expected as what the book says because the program receive `SIGCONT` firstly then `SIGHUP`, which is very confusing for me, can you guys help me out?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The `SIGHUP` cannot be delivered until the child's execution is resumed.  When a process is stopped, all signal delivery is suspended except for `SIGCONT` and `SIGKILL`.

So, the `SIGHUP` does arrive first, but it cannot be processed until the `SIGCONT` awakens the process execution.

Comment: thanks a lot! that is quite subtle since the book did not explain

Comment: @Tracy, you're welcome.  If the answer was helpful, don't hesitate to upvote and/or accept it, thanks.

Comment: +1  I am also wondering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635458/when-several-signals-arrive-at-a-process-what-is-the-order-between-the-process