# How to know which signals are passed when the orphand process created?

Tags: c, signals, fork

I read when the parent process terminates before the child execute that time the child process will send the SIGHUP and SIGCONT signal. then this will work under the init process.
so i want to know child process generate a signal or not?
for that i work out the program like this, but i didn't receive any messages like signal received.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>

void handler(int signo)
{
    if(signo == SIGHUP)
        printf("SIGHUP present\n");
    else if (signo == SIGCONT)
        printf("SIGCONT present\n");
}

main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    signal(SIGCONT,handler);
    signal(SIGHUP,handler);

    if((pid=fork()) == 0)
    {
        sleep(5);                                                                                                                       
        printf("Child terminated\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please could you clarify the first paragraph of your question, paying careful attention to the English. As written, it makes no sense to me. In particular, *what* is meant to be sending `SIGHUP` or `SIGCONT`? I suspect you are trying to ask about process groups and the process group leader here.

Comment: @abligh - when a parent process will terminate before its child executes , then the child become orphand. That time the child process will generate a signal to continue its execution, that signal number is `SIGHUP` AND `SIGCONT` . do you understand or not ??

Comment: @Bhavanesh I understand the individual words (and have a pretty good knowledge of UNIX signal handling), but it doesn't appear to make a lot of sense as a question. I suspect English may not be your first language and I know that makes it more difficult, but I think you will get more success if you carefully phrase your question so the maximum number of people can understand it.

Comment: @abligh - Hmmm ok,Thank you for your response, if i did mistake, u can edit it ,then i will correct it

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17768459/132382

Comment: _I read when the parent process terminates before the child execute that time the child process will send the SIGHUP and SIGCONT signal._ - If you read something and have a question about it, you should state where you read that.

Answer (score 1):

The child is not notified by signal if the parent dies.

The parent receives SIGCHLD if a child dies.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the signal handler works when the process (which registers the handler) receives any signal and not the other way around. 
In your case, if the parent process or the child process receives any signal then the handler will be called. 
Since here the child process is itself generating the signal (as you said, I have not read about this yet), the handler will not called.
Correct me if I am wrong.